# SKScene randomly goes back to main menu

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

Hi in the game I have made it seems when I am playing the game, randomly the gameplay scene goes back to the main menu. This could be an issue beccuase of high score lose and so on. Any possibly known fixes for this?

Thanks

Comment: Yup. Most likely you did not implement viewWillLayoutSubviews with a safety check for repeated execution of that method.

Comment: That is true when you rotate the device and it goes back to main menu.

Comment: How do I use the safey check?? @LearnCocos2D

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
        skView.showsPhysics = YES;

        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

Add this method replace the "viewDidLoad" method in scene.m.